# How to save the objects in the json array in shared preferences?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm fetching details from the server but i just need to know how to save the objects in the json array in the shared preferences

```
 "data": [
        {
            "intrest": "Acting",
            "intrestID": "40a17cc1-17cb-464d-8cc7-308d3c43332a"
        },
        {
            "intrest": "Dancing",
            "intrestID": "b139ee6e-d09a-4ccc-b9e3-5d3567bda66f"
        },
        {
            "intrest": "Singing",
            "intrestID": "cd56d6d6-7c72-4b30-a4c5-23ddbeb94346"
        }
    ]
```

Here i just need to save all the 'interest' objects in the sharedd preferences

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = new List(jsonData.length - 1);
int i = 0;
for (var oneData in jsonData) {
  myArray[i] = oneData["intrest"];
  i++;
}

var encodedMyList = json.encode(myArray);
SharedPreferences myShPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
myShPref.setString('intrests', encodedMyList );
```

Now if you want to access stored data:

```
var myArray = jsonDecode(myShPref.getString('intrests'));
```